# How to insert multiple textboxes with two different names?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3tkJ.png)I'm trying to insert multiple text-boxes with only two names.In all these texboxes I have names items[] and qty[]. I have tried to nest foreach loop but adds more values than expected.The problem is with $_POST['qty']. I can select and add from items[], but I can not add the qty integer value!

```
<div class="col-md-12 diff">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <p>Select Item</p>
                       <input style="color:black;" type="text" class="form-control items" name="items[]" placeholder="Search...">
                    <div class="side"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <p>QTY</p>
                        <input id="pats_input" class="form-control pats_tb" type="text" name="qty[]" placeholder="NO:">
                    <div class="side"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12 diff">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <p>Select Item</p>
                       <input style="color:black;" type="text" class="form-control items" name="items[]" placeholder="Search...">
                    <div class="side"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <p>QTY</p>
                        <input id="pats_input" class="form-control pats_tb" type="text" name="qty[]" placeholder="NO:">
                    <div class="side"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>


function issueToEmployee(){
            global $conn;
           if(isset($_POST['pats']) && $_POST['pats'] !="" && isset($_POST['items']) && $_POST['items'] !="" && isset($_POST['qty'])){
                $perstat = new getPerstat();
                //get employee pats
                $perstat->getPats($_POST['pats']);
                $stock = new StockTable();
                $qty = $_POST['qty'];
                foreach($_POST['items'] as $item){
                    foreach($qty as $q){
                        if(!empty($item) && !empty($q)){
                             $stock->getItemByName($item);
                        $sql = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO issues (empid, itemid) VALUES('$perstat->id','$stock->itemid')");
                        $sql->execute();
                        }
                    }

                }

                return true;

            }else{
                return false;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to point the items on the qty like this:

```
$items = $_POST['items'];
$qty = $_POST['qty'];
foreach($items as $i => $item)
{
 if(!empty($item) && (isset($qty[$i]) && !empty($qty[$i])))
 {
    $stock->getItemByName($item);
    $sql = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO issues (empid,itemid) VALUES('$perstat->id','$stock->itemid')");
    $sql->execute();
  }

}
```

Since Items are corresponds to their qty (correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: Yes, $items = $_POST['items'] since input name is items[], and $qty=$_POST['qty'], input qty[].

Answer (score 0):

I found how to add above values from multiple input fields items[] and qty[],

```
for($i = 0; $i < 8 ; $i++){
                       //$id = $_POST['id'][$i];
                     $description =  $_POST['items'][$i];
                       $qty = $_POST['qty'][$i];
                        $date = $_POST['date'];
                       if(!empty($qty)){
                         $stock->getItemByName($description);
                        $sql = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO issues (empid, itemid, qty, date) VALUES('$perstat->id','$stock->itemid','$qty','$date')");
                          $sql->execute();

                       }

                }
```